# Replacing several lines in arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I'm just trying to look for the next lines in my file...

```
digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(led, LOW);
```

...and replacing them with...

```
point();
```

...but i'm not able to search for more than one line.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be asking about editor capabilities (multi-line search) and not programming per-se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use external editor. I recomend you Sublimetext 3. There is complete tutorial:

- Open sublimetext edior.
- Press CMD + O on Mac or CTRL + O on other platforms. Then open file dialog will show up. Now you choose the file you want to edit.
- Press CMD + shift + F on Mac or CTRL + shift + F on other platforms.
- Now copy the lines you want to replace to **Find:** textbox.
- Write the replacement text to **Replace:** textbox.

[image: Setup replacing]

- Click replace button.
- Click **Replace** button in message box.

[image: messagebox]

- Now it is done!

[image]